# Resolve c++ pointer-to-member error in VS 2003

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

I have a c++ program that I'm trying to port from VS98 to VS2003 (incremental steps).  One error that occurs throughout is "Error 2275"

For instance:  k:\RR\chart\chartdlg.cpp(2025): error C2475: 'CRrDoc::cFldFilter' : forming a pointer-to-member requires explicit use of the address-of operator ('&') and a qualified name

The offending code is shown below:

```
void CDataPage::OnBtnLabelField()
{
    FLDID       fid ;
    LPMFFIELD   f ;
    CRrApp  *pApp = (CRrApp *)AfxGetApp();
    CMainFrame *pFrame = (CMainFrame *)AfxGetMainWnd();
    CRrDoc  *pDoc = (CRrDoc *)pFrame->GetActiveDocument();
    CSelectFieldDlg dlg;

    //**************************************************
    //BOOL CRrDoc::*zcFldFilter = &CRrDoc::cFldFilter;

    //dlg.ck = CRrDoc->*zcFldFilter;
    //**************************************************

    dlg.ck = pDoc->cFldFilter ;

    dlg.TitleTextID = IDS_2676;
    fid = (FLDID)dlg.DoModal();

    if (fid != NOID)
    {
        f = pDoc->m_pComposite->mfbyndx(fid);

        // find index
        int i, iCount;
        iCount = m_lboxLabel.GetCount();
        for (i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
        {
            if(fid == m_lboxLabel.GetItemData(i))
            {
                m_lboxLabel.SetCurSel(i);
                OnSelchangeComboLabel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried handling it according to a Microsoft [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx):  But that just generated a set of other problems (the commented code between the asterisks).  Note that I also commented out the following line:

```
dlg.ck = pDoc->cFldFilter
```

Unfortunately, this leads to a new error:  k:\RR\chart\chartdlg.cpp(2022): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(LPMFFIELD)' to 'BOOL CRrDoc::* '

The definition in the .H file looks like:

```
public:
        static BOOL cFldFilter(LPMFFIELD f);
```

Any ideas how to handle the pointer-to-member issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have:

```
static BOOL CRrDoc::cFldFilter(LPMFFIELD f);
```

its type is not a member variable but a function:

```
//BOOL CRrDoc::*zcFldFilter = &CRrDoc::cFldFilter;    // doesn't work
BOOL (*zcFldFilter)(LPMFFIELD) = &CRrDoc::cFldFilter; // works
```

Since dlg.ck is of a correct type, you should do

```
dlg.ck = &CRrDoc::cFldFilter;
```

Comment: Your suggestion resolved the p-2-m error but the compiler now throws "'CRrDoc' : illegal use of this type as an expression"  What can I provide to give more / better insight into what's going on?

Comment: which is the type of CSelectFieldDlg::ck ?

Comment: I also looked up the definition of dlg.ck; it's an integer: `int (*ck)(LPMFFIELD)`

Comment: you're wrong, it is not an integer, but it is a pointer on function (which takes a LPMFFIELD and) returning an int whereas CRrDoc::cFldFilter return a BOOL instead (I don't know how BOOL is defined/typedefed in your case). You may change the definition of the function nor the pointer of function to match each other, or use reinterpret_cast<int(*)(LPMFFIELD)>(&CRrDoc::cFldFilter).

Comment: Thanks.  I realized shortly after I posted that the pointer was the integer.  The various VS2003 files where BOOL is listed all show `typedef int BOOL`

Comment: answer updated since I have more info. Note that your commented code should be removed now.